# The RD Connection Broker server is not available

Tags: powershell, amazon-rds, remote-desktop

I am trying to run the command Get-RDServer on a remote computer. Unfortunately, I get the following error message every time.
[Local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPFQ5.png)

It works when I run the command directly on the server.
[Remote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXovS.png)

Am I missing something? How can I properly configure the RD Connection Broker server?